# Zend_Form label decorator

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I have a problem with label decorator. When I generate a form I have something like this:

```
<label id="user_email-label"><label for="user_email" class="required">e-mail</label>
</label>
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" class="span4">
```

but I need :

```
<label for="user_email" class="required">e-mail</label>
<input type="text" name="user_email" id="user_email" value="" class="span4">
```

My code:

```
$oText = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('user_email');
$oText->clearDecorators();
$oText->setLabel($oTranslate->translate('e-mail'));
$oText->setAttrib('class','span4');
$oText->setRequired(true);
$oText->addValidator('NotEmpty', true);
$oText->addValidator('StringLength', true, array('max' => 200));
$oText->addValidator('EmailAddress', true);
$oText->addDecorator('ViewHelper');
$oText->addDecorator('Errors');
$oText->addDecorator('Label',array('tag'=>'label', 'placement' => 'prepend'));
$oText->setFilters(array('StringToLower','StringTrim'));
$this->addElement($oText);
```

And my second question is how can I put a checkbox inside label? When I am doing something like this:

```
 $oCheckbox = new Zend_Form_Element_Checkbox('remember_me');
    $oCheckbox->setLabel($oTranslate->translate('remember me'));
    $oCheckbox->setChecked(true);
    $oCheckbox->addDecorator('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'label','class'=>'checkbox muted'));
    $oCheckbox->removeDecorator('DtDdWrapper');
    $oCheckbox->addDecorator('Label',array('tag'=>'label'));
    $this->addElement($oCheckbox);
```

I have:

```
<label class="checkbox muted">
<input type="hidden" name="remember_me" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" value="1" checked="checked"></label>
<label id="remember_me-label"><label for="remember_me" class="optional">remember me</label></label>
```

but I need:

```
<label class="checkbox muted">
<input type="hidden" name="remember_me" value="0"><input type="checkbox" name="remember_me" id="remember_me" value="1" checked="checked">
remember me</label>
```

Any ideas?

Regards

Comment: If you have two questions, please ask two. It is a bit confusing to have them both in one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The part where you build your element, the 'tag' option

```
$oText->addDecorator('Label',array('tag'=>'label', 'placement' => 'prepend'));`
```

is not needed. Change it to:

```
$oText->addDecorator('Label',array('placement' => 'prepend'));
```

As for the second question, I think you would have to write your custom element to achieve that. Alternatively, you can use the view script to render each part of the element as you like.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for help. I try build a custom decorator class, my code:

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your second query is to use the IMPLICIT_APPEND placement on the label decorator.

```
    $oCheckbox->addDecorator('Label',array('placement' => 'IMPLICIT_APPEND'));
```